# Windows 10 Universal App, Reference Local SQLite DB file

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, sqlite, win-universal-app

I'm getting closer to having a functional SQLite Database in my Universal App.

I keep getting the error 'Cannot Open' and I feel it might be a path problem as SQL Toolbox for Visual Studio picks up the .db file fine.

How to I reference the .db should i put it in a new folder? I need to perform operations to this database but information on this in VB.NET is extremely limited!

Here is what I have so far:

```
    Dim platform As New SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT
    Dim lc As New SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(platform, "/myDB.db")

    lc.Execute("INSERT INTO lcCust (CName) VALUES ('Hello')")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now successfully created a db using a GUI program. This one specify is SQLiteStudio. I created the DB and connected to it using the SQLite-PCL package along with the Visual Studio addon